# Linking errors when trying to build GLFW

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm using CMAKE to build GLFW, but its spewing out the following error: `No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.`. [This](http://pastebin.com/ZAkFgiPS) is the entire output log, though i think the important bit is:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ucrtd.lib'

I've done some searching and it seems like my Visual Studio installation is fried, when i try to repair it i get a ton of errors about packages that cannot be found. I've tried to reinstall some C++ redist and the Windows 7 SDK, though that didnt fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

You need to specify the generator when running cmake, if you use VS2013:

```
cmake . -G "Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64"
```

For Visual Studio 2015 it should be

```
cmake . -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"
```

[Here is the complete list of generators.](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#ide-build-tool-generators) Maybe you have to leave out the "Win64" part.

Original post:

According to

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1160492/linker-errors-after-upgrading-from-ctp5-to-ctp6

you could try to add $UniversalCRT_LibraryPath to Configuration Properties -> VC++Directories -> Library Directories. Does this solve your problem?

One thing you could also try is to uninstall and then reinstall MSVC.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! The error comes out of the CMAKE command, not in Visual Studio itself. Just to be clear, i browse to my GLFW folder and execute `cmake .` Visual Studio can build projects just fine.

Comment: @TJHeuvel I updated my answer. You should specify VS as your generator.

Comment: I've tried that, to no avail. I even tried VS 2013 since i have that installed too, but got the same error as listed in the question.